# PROBLEMA al crear un TRIGGER MYSQL con diferentes tablas y un IF

Tags: mysql, condiciones, trigger, tablas, insert

tengo una tabla ''Libro'' que tiene un campo Stock, además tengo una tabla ''detalle venta'' que tiene un campo cantidad, en el cual se almacena la cantidad de libros comprados.
Quiero crear un trigger que antes de insertar el dato ''cantidad'' en la tabla ''Detalle venta'' verifique que dicha cantidad sea menor que el stock en la tabla libro, ya que si es mayor el campo ''cantidad'' tomará el valor que tiene el ''stock'' y el stock quedará en 0

Aquí está el código que hice, el trigger se crea, pero al momento de insertar datos en la tabla ''detalle venta'' dice ''unknow table libro in field list''

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER Libro_BI_ControlStock BEFORE INSERT ON Detalle_Venta
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 DECLARE Nvalor INT DEFAULT 0;
 SET Nvalor=NEW.cantidad;
 IF NEW.cantidad<Libro.Stock THEN
    UPDATE Libro 
    Set Stock=Stock-Nvalor
    Where ISBN=Detalle_Venta.Libro;
 ELSEIF NEW.cantidad>Libro.Stock THEN
    UPDATE Libro
    Set Stock=0
    Where ISBN=Detalle_venta.Libro;
    SET NEW.cantidad=Libro.Stock;
 END IF;
END //
Delimiter ;
```

Antes que nada, debo trabajar así ya que así lo pide el ejercicio, pero ya intenté de todo y no sé como acceder al stock de la tabla libro en el IF

De antemano agradezco sus respuesta.

Aquí está la creación de las tablas

```
create table if not exists Libro(
    ISBN Int(10) primary key,
    Titulo Varchar(50) not null,
    Area Varchar(40) not null,
    Costo Float(4,2) not null,  
    PVP Float(4,2) not null,
    Stock Int(4) not null
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table if not exists Venta(
        IDventa Int(10) Primary key,
    Cliente Int(10) not null,
    Fecha Date Not null,
        Total Float(5,2) Not null,
    Saldo Float(6,2) Not null,
        Pago Int(10) Not null -- ,
        -- Foreign key(Cliente) References Cliente(CI),
        -- Foreign Key(Pago) References Pago(IDpago)   
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table if not exists Detalle_Venta(
        Venta Int(10),
        Libro Int(10),
        PVP Float(4,2) Not null,
        Cantidad Int(4) Not null,
        Primary key(Venta,Libro),
        Foreign key(Venta) References Venta(IDventa),
        Foreign Key(Libro) References Libro(ISBN) 
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Estoy trabajando con la consola por lo que se me complica el uso de phpmyadmin(o se no estoy seguro de como utilizarlo)

Comment: Pásanos el resto del dataset: el SQL de creación de las tablas y algún dato de muestra, con phpmyadmin, exportar, para hacer las pruebas necesarias

Comment: Como primeros comentarios: Sustituya `Detalle_venta.Libro` por `NEW.Libro` entendido que representa el libro a vender. Debe buscar el `Stock` del libro en particular a vender, `Libro.Stock` no representa ningún libro en particular. La definición de tablas así como datos de pruebas, como comentan anteriormente, facilitan la ayuda.

Comment: Ya agregué la creación de las tablas, Libro en detalle venta hace referencia al pk de la tabla Libro
Estoy casi seguro de que el error es en el IF ya que estoy tratando de acceder a ''Libro'' pero no lo estoy llamando antes del UPDATE.
Además de que cuando pongo Libreria.Libro.Stock también me dice que ''Libreria.Libro'' unknow in field list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí lo tienes:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER Libro_BI_ControlStock
  BEFORE INSERT ON Detalle_Venta
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE vStock INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT Stock INTO vStock FROM Libro
      WHERE ISBN=new.Libro;
    IF NEW.cantidad<vStock THEN
      UPDATE Libro 
      Set Stock=Stock-NEW.Cantidad
      Where ISBN=NEW.Libro;
    ELSEIF NEW.cantidad>=vStock THEN
      UPDATE Libro
      Set Stock=0
      Where ISBN=NEW.Libro;
      SET NEW.cantidad=vStock;
    END IF;
   END//
```

Te has liado un poco entre campos y variables, pero ya casi lo tenías.

Comment: Gracias, eso era lo que quería pero nadie me dijo como guardar una consulta en una variable, incluso pensé en un procedure jajs
Fuiste de gran ayuda :)

Comment: Hay dos formas, también serviría un `SET vStock=(SELECT ...)`. Me alegra que te haya resultado útil :)